# How to anchor GameObject on environment using Vuforia device tracking markerless and unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, game-engine, vuforia, game-development

I'm using unity and vuforia and I have similar project to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mpx6IMUR0yw.

Is it possible to resolve the problem at 7:46? I want to walk towards the object and that it does not move so that I can go through it.

I can do this when I use ground plane but I don't want to place the object on the floor but place it in a random position 360 degrees around me.

Comment: wouldn't the ground plane only be your anchor ... it doesn't mean your object necessary is placed on the floor ... only relative to it ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SLAM functions in vuforia,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pk_ABmk1cPM
as seen at 2.04

https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/features/environments/area-targets.html

"SLAM (Simultaneous Localization and Mapping) is a technology which understands the physical world through feature points. This makes it possible for AR applications to Recognize 3D Objects & Scenes, as well as to Instantly Track the world, and to overlay digital interactive augmentations"

Comment: But I dont want to point a place and click to make the object appear. I want the objects appear at a random position in the air. I don't need to recognise planes (floor) or anything

Comment: If u just want it to appear, truly randomly, u can just spawn a gameobject, maybe relative to your camera object, infront of your camera? then set it to move towards your camera object, that's all you need if you dont want tracking. It's a kind of gimmick but may serve your purposes

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain it well... I have done EXACTLY  what this guy do in the video. I want the object appear in front of my camera but I want since the moment the object appears, is trackable with the environment. I want to be capable to get closer to the object without it moves away from my camera.